# Flipping textPath direction from anti-clockwise to clockwise?

Tags: html, css, svg

By default, SVG wraps text around a path in an anti-clockwise manner. The ceiling of the text sticks the path. How to change the direction to clockwise so that the floor of the text sticks to the circumference instead of the ceiling?

```css
.textspace {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
  writing-mode: tb;
}

.curved-text {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <defs>
    <path   d="M60,60
          A50,50
          0 
          1,0
          61,60"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-width="2"
          fill="none"
          id="tracker-path"/>
  </defs>
  
  <text x="50" y="50" class="curved-text">
    <textPath xlink:href="#tracker-path">
      Tracking succesful.
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this. All you need to do is set the value of `sweep-flag` from `0` to `1`. That will flip the direction of `path`

```css
.textspace
{
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 50px;
 writing-mode: tb;
}

.curved-text
{
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <defs>
   <path  d="M80,160
      A50,50
      0 
      1,1
      81,160"
      stroke="black"
      stroke-width="2"
      fill="none"
      id="tracker-path"/>
  </defs>
  <text x="50" y="50" class="curved-text">
   <textPath xlink:href="#tracker-path">
    Tracking succesful.
   </textPath>
  </text>
 </svg>
```