# Change the direction of text in CSS SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have following SVG code: https://jsfiddle.net/danpan/m3ofzrc1/ that generates the blow image.

There are two lines of texts -- around a circle:

HELLO_WORLD_1

HELLO_WORLD_2

How to change the direction of one of the line, "HELLO_WORLD_2" to be clock wise?

[image]

```
<svg width="132" height="132">
  <defs>
    <path id="text-path" d="M66 126A60 60 0 1 0 66 6a60 60 0 0 0 0 120" fill="none"/>
  </defs>

  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#text-path" font-family="Manrope3-ExtraBold, Manrope3" font-size="10" font-weight="600" fill="#001A62" letter-spacing="3.14">HELLO_WORLD_1 * HELLO_WORLD_2</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: With Firefox you could just use the side property e.g. side="right" but I don't think Chrome/Safari have implemented side yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
To solve this, you need to split the text and the path into two parts. The top of the text will follow the top path. The lower part of the text, respectively, along the lower path.

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="-10 -10 150 150" >
    <!--  sweep-flag="1" Clockwise text direction -->
   <path id="top-path"  d="M6 66A60 60 0 1 1 126 66" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
  <!--  sweep-flag="0" Counterclockwise text direction -->
<path  id="bottom-path" d="M6 66A60 60 0 1 0 126 66" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>
 </svg>
```

Both halves of the text will start from the same point with coordinates `M6 66` and end at the same point `126 66` But the upper part of the text will go clockwise `sweep-flag = "1"` The lower part of the text is counterclockwise  `sweep-flag = "0"`

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="-10 -10 150 150" >
  <defs> 
          <!--  sweep-flag="1" Clockwise text direction -->
   <path id="top-path"  d="M6 66A60 60 0 1 1 126 66" fill="none" />
           <!--  sweep-flag="0" Counterclockwise text direction -->
<path  id="bottom-path" d="M6 66A60 60 0 1 0 126 66" fill="none" />
  </defs>
  <text dx="30" dy="-2">
    <textPath xlink:href="#top-path" font-family="Manrope3-ExtraBold, Manrope3" font-size="10" font-weight="600" fill="#001A62" letter-spacing="3.14">HELLO_WORLD_1 </textPath>
</text> 
 <text dx="20" dy="10">
    <textPath xlink:href="#bottom-path" font-family="Manrope3-ExtraBold, Manrope3" font-size="10" font-weight="600" fill="#001A62" letter-spacing="3.14">* HELLO_WORLD_2</textPath>
</text> 
</svg>
```

### Tl;dr

The text will be located along the arc from its start point (Arc start) to the end point (Arc end)
But what path it will take from the starting point to the final - Arc end, depends on the parameters
**large-arc-flag** and **sweep-flag**

[image]

Your variant of the text arrangement - bottom row red line

**[9.3.8. The elliptical arc curve commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands)**

```
<path d="M6 66A60 60 0 1 1 126 66" /> 
<path d="M mx,my A rx,ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag, sweep-flag x,y" />  , where
```

- **M mx,my** – coordinates of the starting point of the ellipse arc
- **A rx, ry** - ellipse arc radii
- **x-axis-rotation** – of the ellipse is rotated by x-axis-rotation degrees relative to the x-axis of the current coordinate system
- **large-arc-flag** - parameter that implements the output of most of the arc, if (= 1) or less (= 0)
- **sweep-flag** - implements the direction of drawing the arc from the start point to the end point. If sweep-flag = 1, then the ellipse arc
  will be drawn clockwise. With sweep-flag = 0 - counterclockwise.
- **x,y** – coordinates of the end point of the ellipse arc

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<path id="text-path" d="M66 126A60 60 0 1 1 66 6a60 60 0 0 1 0 120" fill="none"/>
```

reference:
[Flipping textPath direction from anti-clockwise to clockwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588905/flipping-textpath-direction-from-anti-clockwise-to-clockwise)

Comment: Thank you. But, it flip the entire text; I want to flip only one line (half of the text)